Side Length of a Triangle with a Circle (Detent Mechanism)

Simple question, but I've slammed my head against a wall on it for a couple of hours . I know all the variables except for $l$. All the red lines are angles. The boxed red lines indicate a right angle. Can someone help me find an expression for $l$ in terms of $\theta$?
Context:
I am trying to calculate the torque needed to overcome a rotational detent mechanism. Getting an expression for $l$ will help me determine the change in length of the plunger for a given rotational value $\theta$ and hence the force generated by the plunger's spring. Of course, it would be easier for me just to build the thing and test it, but I'd like to have the theory behind it as well.
What I've tried:
Standard law of cosines, law of sines, triangle properties, etc. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and I posted here just in case someone has solved a similar problem like this in the past. I'm kind of stumped.
Thank you!

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Note that, as your diagram is currently drawn, the specific values of $a$ and $b$ don't make a difference (actually, with $\gamma$ being given, specifying one allows the other to be determined from $\tan(\gamma)=\frac{a}{b}$) since one could, for example, extend the hypotenuse in the triangle with angle $\gamma$ down so $a$ and $b$ would become larger, without this affecting anything else, including the value of $l$.

Ah, yes, my mistake. Diagram should be fixed now. Thanks!

I still don’t see how you can determine $l$ from the given data. Perhaps you want the left corner of the inclined plane to coincide with the point of contact of the circle and the inclined plane? Otherwise, $a$ doesn’t yield any useful information.
